# Very simple js calculator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

What did I do wrong?

**HTML**

```
<form name="Calc">
    <BR>
    <input type="text" name="1" size="20">*
    <input type="text" name="2" size="20">=
    <input type="text" name="sum" size="20">
    <BR>
    <input type="button" name="Calc" value="Calculate" onClick="calcsum()">
</form>
```

**Script**

```
function calcsum() {
    sum.value = 1.value * 2.value;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vrfw9/

Comment: Property and variable names cannot start with numbers. Change the name to something more meaningful (like `number1`) or better, use IDs and `document.getElementById` instead of `name.value` (it is discouraged).

Comment: Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/2nXTC/

Comment: @PhistucK agree with your comment but "cannot start" should be "should not" because Demo prepared by "laaposto" is working well.

Comment: Then I did not get the relevance comment.. @PhistucK. Here the only violation is in name not in property and variable.

Comment: Correction - *should not. Thank you, @PM..

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)

Try:

```
function calcsum() {
    document.getElementsByName("sum")[0].value = document.getElementsByName("1")[0].value * document.getElementsByName("2")[0].value;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vrfw9/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a reference to the button in the listener:

```
<input type="button" ... onclick="calcsum(this)">
```

Then in the function you can use it to get a reference to the form and its other controls by name:

```
function calcsum(button) {
    var form = button.form;
    sum.value = form['1'].value * form['2'].value;
}
```

Note that form control values are always strings, so be careful with using `+` for addition.

I'm not a fan of mixed case for HTML attribute names. They are not case sensitive, but their related DOM properties are. So better to use "onclick" for the attribute to match the DOM "onclick" property.